# How to fix the parameter was not supplied on Crystal report after modifying stored procedure

Tags: visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports

I have an old crystal report in VS2008. I have changed the parameters, adding two new parameters (`@parameterThree` and `@parameterFour`) and have deleted one parameter on my stored procedure.

I have gone to `Database -> Verify Database` to force the report to see the modified procedure. However, it still shows the old 3 parameters name without the new parameters.

When I click OK, it shows the error:

> Query Engine Error: '42000:[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL
>   Server]Procedure or function 'myReport' expects parameter
>   '@parameterFour which not supplied.'

I have added the new parameters on the new parameter Fields in Field Explorer. The new parameters I added on the report didn't have checkmark.

I have done the `Verify Database` again but it still doesn't work.

I am unable to delete the old parameter which is not in my modified store procedure.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by using "Set Datasource Location". There is my step:
Click Set Datasource Location-->Select the query in the Current Data Source box --> Select the query in the Replace with box--> click Update button.

Comment: After doing this, "Verify Database" stills throws the same error. Any idea how to solve it?